# Represent this data into matrix form in C

Tags: c, matrix, plot

I wrote a code as per below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  #define SIZE 1000

  FILE *fp = NULL;
  int i = 0;
  size_t  bytes = 0;

  if ((fp = fopen("raw_data.ht3", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf ("could not open file\n");
    return 0;
  }
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

This just give me single integer for every data read. I need to present this data in a matrix form. The matrix will be in the form of 500 by 349. How could I present the data like that? From this data, I will later on make a matrix plot. thanks! Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have your data in order? You can just iterate matrix with 2 for loops and add new elements there.

Comment: Which is the file format of data?

Comment: @Mare70 yeah the data is in order. so all Im getting is one row of data. I need a row and a column. so thats that.

Comment: @alseether it is in .ht3 format. with the code above i could read the format correctly.. just need to represent it in matrix form so i can do a matrix plot in matlab

Comment: @hphys Just a bidimensional array then

Comment: @hphys try something from this search, or you can wait someone to write you full answer ^^ https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+from+file+and+store+in+matrix+c&rlz=1C1GGRV_enRS748RS748&oq=how+to+read+from+file+and+store+in+matrix+c&aqs=chrome..69i57.18803j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Aside: Why 2 in `fread(&su.shint, 2, SIZE, fp))`?  Consider `sizeof su.shint[0]` instead.

Comment: How does code hope to save 500 by 349 integers in `su`.  `SIZE 1000` is far too small.  Too much code is not done nor attempted - very broad.

Comment: @chux 2 cuz 2 bytes... okay, that sounds good

Comment: @hphys `short` is not defined to be 2 bytes, even though it often is.

Comment: Removing your code from original question doesn't make your question less broad; Indeed, your question are worst than original version

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the union you currently have, do this:

```
typedef union
{
  uint8_t  u8 [2];
  uint16_t u16;
} meaningful_name_here;
```

Then you can either do

```
meaningful_name_here stuff [1000];
```

or

```
meaningful_name_here stuff [500][349];
```

Also please keep in mind that large arrays like these should not be allocated on the stack. Allocate them as `static` or with dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: how do i present the data in this case?